How to combine these two tables
please do anyone have idea on how to do this with googlesheets
Table 1



Countries
Currency




Nigeria
Ngn


Canada
Cad


USA
Usd



Table 2



Countries
Continent




Nigeria
Africa


India
Asia


Germany
Europe



I want to accomplish this



Countries
Continent
Currency




Nigeria
Africa
Ngn


India
Asia



Germany
Europe



Canada

Cad


USA

Usd



Any idea is welcome... Thanks

You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(c,UNIQUE(TOCOL({D2:D;A2:A},1)),IFNA({c,VLOOKUP(c,D2:E,2,0),VLOOKUP(c,A2:B,2,0)})))


